# aggregate method from multicall3 fails. is there any limits on number of batched calls?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, evm, polygon-pos

i am trying to call aggregate method of multicall3 contract (0xcA11bde05977b3631167028862bE2a173976CA11) on polygon.

when i pass 64 batched requests to retrieve balances of WMATIC token from 64 different addresses all works.

though, when i pass 65 batches or more i receive:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":100,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"}}
```

what could be the problem?

tried multicall2 (0x275617327c958bD06b5D6b871E7f491D76113dd8) and multicall3 contracts...

Comment: You need to provide more details. The question is too broad right now. This is just a generic tx reverted message. Does that call work for each one of the 65 batches on its own?

Comment: i see.. ok. i will add more details. and yes, if i split whole addresses to several batches 64 addresses each all works without problem. the only problem when i trying to make a call with 65 or more addresses in one request. i use private alchemy RPC endpoint

Comment: Well since it only fails at >64 and assuming all the individual calls are correct, my only guess is that it runs out of gas. Maybe check the gas consumption for 64 calls and if thats close to the block limit then the gas should be the issue.

Comment: hmm... but i do "read" operations (getting balances of different tokens from given address). so, i just call "balanceOf" method  from different contracts using an address as parameter.